# Mockito test coming back as zero

Tags: spring

I am trying to get call method called totalmoney() to get the total money in the h2 database but it always returns 0.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MoneyTests {

     @InjectMocks
     MoneyServiceImplementation MoneyServiceImplementation;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllMoney() {

        long total_money = MoneyServiceImplementation.TotalMoney();
         assertEquals("2000", total_money);

}}
```

But it will return the right amount of 2000 by:

```
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Bean.xml");

    MoneyService MoneyService  = (MoneyService) context.getBean("MoneyServiceImplementation");

long total_money = MoneyService.TotalMoney();
```

So what am i doing wrong in the test that it will not work?

Answer (score 0):

> Mockito is not an dependency injection framework, don't expect this shorthand utility to inject a complex graph of objectsbe it mocks/spies or real objects.
>
> Again, note that @InjectMocks will only inject mocks/spies created using the @Spy or @Mock annotation.

There are no any `@Mock` or `@Spy` annotated beans in your test, so all of the dependencies in the created `MoneyServiceImplementation`  are `null`.